# OpenVAS fails to respond with more than 8192 bytes

Tags: openvas

I'm requesting a HTML report from an OpenVAS server the following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<commands><authenticate><credentials><username>***</username><password>***</password></credentials></authenticate><get_reports report_id="454a3397-b8a4-408e-9f55-f08972765d30" format_id="b993b6f5-f9fb-4e6e-9c94-dd46c00e058d"/></commands>
```

However when I read the response I receive only 8192 bytes, which happens not to hold all the HTML code. Is this is a hardcoded limit? How do I get around it?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a similar issue. The cause was related to running

```
openvas-mkcert-client -n admin -i
```

Note the trailing -i, this is what causes the break. I have found no solution.